# How to open fragment with Firebase push notification?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, push-notification, firebase

i am building an app where i am using Firebase push notifications. I have 3 fragment on MainActivity(Fragment1, Fragment2, Fragment3). When user click on push notification, i want to send him to Fragment1. Could you help me?
This is my MainActivity(do not pay attention to comment lines, that was my unsuccesfull effort to solve this problem)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dugme1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dugme2);
    btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dugme3);
    dugme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("developeri");
            Log.d(TAG, "Subscribed to developeri topic");
        }
    });

    Fragment newFra;
    String menuFragment=getIntent().getStringExtra("menuFragment");
    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

    StartFragment startFragment=new StartFragment();
    ft.add(R.id.myFragment, startFragment);
    ft.commit();
    btn1.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);

}
 Button.OnClickListener  btnOnClickListener= new Button.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         Fragment newFragment;
         if (view==btn1){
             newFragment =new Fragment1();

         }else if(view==btn2){
              newFragment =new Fragment2();
         }else if (view==btn3){
             newFragment =new Fragment3();
         }else{
             newFragment=new StartFragment();
         }
         FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, newFragment);
         transaction.addToBackStack(null);
         transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
         transaction.commit();


     }
 };
```

And this is my `FCMessagingService`

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d("OnMessage", "Received");
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d(TAG, "From " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Body " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    Intent intent=new Intent(MyFireBaseMessagingService.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("menuFragment", "Fragment1");




    // remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

}




private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            //.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setContentTitle("ASP")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I know that I must carry something with Intent from FCMessagingService but I dont know where to put it in MainActivity.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In Send Notification…

```
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(context, mainActivity.class);
    Intent broadcast = new Intent(“broadcaster”);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

In MainActivity…

```
    private BroadcastReceiver mReciever;

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver,
    new IntentFilter(“broadcaster”));


   mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


   //code to switch to correct fragment

   }
```

Comment: May I do all this in OnCreate in MyActivity??

Comment: Yeah, you can.. Actually, just realised I misread the original problem. Sorry, but you need to set up an pending intent for your notification. This intent will be for your main activity, put an extra in it to tell you which fragment you want. In your main activity retrieve extras, if it's come from the notification then go to the correct fragment.

Comment: But I have a Pending Intent :) But it dont want to give option pendindIntent.putExtra..And what to put there?

Comment: sendNotification - intent.putExtra("action","gotoFragment1"); thenin MainActivity after the setOnClicks Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); if (extras.getString("action").contentContains("gotoFragement1"){ //switch to fragment1 }

Comment: I dont have option .contentContains("gotoFragment1") just .contains("gotoFragment1")..i hope thats the same... And how to switch to fragment1? Sory for bondering you, this is my last question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a local broadcast receiver. When you get the notification fire off a local broadcast. In your activity, when you receive the local broadcast, change to the correct fragment.

Comment: I newer use local broadcast receiver. Could You write me that lines, please?